# Python regular expression to parse a list into text for a response

Tags: python, regex

When I run the code below I get:

```
    Thank you for joining, ['cars', 'gas', 'jewelry']but['bus', 'join'] are not keywords.
```

How can I effectively turn the lists in to just strings to be printed? I suspect I may need a regular expression... this time :)

```
    import re   

    pattern = re.compile('[a-z]+', re.IGNORECASE)

    text = "join cars jewelry gas bus"
    keywordset = set(('cars', 'jewelry', 'gas', 'food', 'van', 'party', 'shoes'))
    words = pattern.findall(text.lower())
    notkeywords = list(set(words) - keywordset)
    keywords = list(keywordset & set(words))

        if notkeywords == ['join']:
            print "Thank you for joining keywords " + str(keywords) + "!"
        else:
            print "Thank you for joining, " + str(keywords) + "but" + str(notkeywords) + " are not keywords."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert list to strings use [str.join](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) like this

```
print "Thank you for joining keywords " + ",".join(keywords) + "!"
```

This `if notkeywords == ['join']:` is not a way to compare list elements.

```
>>> mylist = [1,2]
>>> mylist == 1
False
```

you should `in` operator to check for equality.

```
>>> mylist = [1,2]
>>> 1 in mylist
True
```

Comment: To expand of the list comparison, you probably actually just want `if 'join' in notkeywords:`.  Python has a great element in a list comparison operator.

Comment: @Xentac: yeah i totally forgot about that.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `someString.join(list)`:

```
        if notkeywords == ['join']:
            print "Thank you for joining keywords " + ", ".join(keywords) + "!"
        else:
            print "Thank you for joining, " + ", ".join(keywords) + "but" + ", ".join(notkeywords) + " are not keywords."
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you'll want to use the .join() string method to combine the list before printing it.

For example:

', '.join(my_list)

will give you comma separated output.  ', ' can be whatever kind of separator you like.